# Setting an entity property DB properties to IsRequired() and defaultValue: "('')" workaround?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF Core 2 and am trying to create Entity properties that are not null with a default value of a blank space.  I'm using the fluent API.  The end result is a default data binding of N'('''')' on the SqlServer side.  I'm fairly certain this is a bug, but is there a known workaround?

I've tried string manipulation to account for the extra apostrophes as well as a variable.  However, when I look at the migration script, it's correct so it seems it's happening between the update-database and server communication process and is out of my control.

```
public class EfficacyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PersonType> PersonType { get; protected set; }

    public EfficacyDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PersonEntityTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PersonTypeEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }
}
public class PersonEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Person.Person");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(x => x.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasDefaultValue("('')").IsRequired();
    }
}
```

On the SqlServer side I expect the field to default to a blank value when nothing is entered.  However, because of the skewy data binding, I get a default value of ('')

Comment: Please mark Ivan's answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [HasDefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hasdefaultvalue?view=efcore-2.1) method incorrectly. It expects a *value* while your are passing *SQL fragment*. The later is supported, but by a different method -  [HasDefaultValueSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hasdefaultvaluesql?view=efcore-2.1).

So either use

```
.HasDefaultValue("")
```

or

```
.HasDefaultValueSql("('')")
```

**Reference:** EF Core documentation - [Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values)

Comment: Ahhh, I totally missed 'Sql' at the end of .HadDefaultValue.  Both work.  Sorry Microsoft for assuming it was a bug.  Much obliged Ivan.

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately MS released many bugs in EF Core, so we started suspecting bugs even if they aren't :)